# Office 365 API : How to solve Mac PDF template error: "A footer of section 1 is set outside the printable area of the page

Tags: javascript, pdf, ms-word, office-js, office365api

I am getting an error like "A footer of section 1 is set outside the printable area of the page" while generate pdf document on MAC.

I am using Office 365 API to generate PDF document(Office.context.document.getFileAsync). As soon as i click on generate pdf , it is giving me popup on mac machine says "A footer of section 1 is set outside the printable area of the page" etc...

Same method working fine on windows environment.

Thanks
Keyur Patel

Comment: Hello, it would be wonderful if you can add a pointer to the document where you are experiencing this to investigate the issue more effectively.

Comment: Hi Juan Balmori, I didn't get your point. I am using following method to generate PDF. Everytime, it will popup message in MAC word when header and footer exist in document. I am using following method.
     Office.context.document.getFileAsync(officeFileType, { slicesize: 65536 }, function (result: Office.AsyncResult) {

Comment: this happens with any document? Please send me the version of Word for Mac you are using.

Comment: Mac Word Version 15:32. Yes, it happens with any document. Create Document and add header and footer in document , try to generate PDF using "getFileAsync" method. You will get popup message says "A footer of section 1 is set outside the printable area of the page" Make sure your Header and Footer from edge by default 1.27 cm. Looks like this shouldn't issue with office 365 API. this issue also happen with manually save as docs as PDF on mac.

Comment: where can i download a copy of this document causing you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this issue. This is a bug in the product and we are working to ship a fix as soon as possible.